# Display Chinese comment in Eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, encoding, utf-8

I'm working in a project that have Chinese character that I want to understand. So I want to change the character format to display these Chinese character.

What I have tried:

1. Window - Preferences - General - Content Type - Change Default
2. Encoding to UTF-8 Window - Preferences - General - Workspace - Text
       file encoding change to UTF-8

But seem like it's not work. See the images for more detail.

Before change to UTF-8:

[image]

After changed to UTF-8 it's look something like this:

[image]

One more problem is the change also effect to git status.

So my main question is how can I display the Chinese character in Eclipse editor (without changed git status).

Thanks.

Addtional information: when open file by Notepad++ the Chinese character show correctly.

Comment: You need to find out what the encoding of the source file is. Which one does Notepad++ use?

Answer (score 4):

It's depending on the encoding when the file saved.

Try change to `GBK` , `ISO-8859-1` , `GBK2312`.
And you also can try copy content from Notepad++ to IDE.

Hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Right click your project. Select Resource -> Other and select UTF-8 and do apply. After that rebuild your project.

[image]

Comment: How do you know the file is in UTF-8?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all of your answer but seem like there is no completely one so I will post my answer (upvoted you guys).

Since the UTF-8 is not work I tried to change to GBK and the Chinese character displayed correctly then.

Right click project - Properties - Resource - Textfile Encoding - Other - set to GBK

Answer (score 1):

Since Notepad++ cannot detect a foreign code page, it's unlikely that it's a native code page like `GB2312`. It's more likely that Notepad++ detects a UTF-16 code page (with or without BOM). To be sure, check the Encoding pulldown menu in Notepad++.

This is also backed by what you see. Before the UTF-8 selection, you see weird characters, but you also see `LdapConfig`. After the UTF-8 selection, `LdapConfig` is gone, replaced by �. Had the original been UTF-8, `LdapConfig` would still be `LdapConfig`.

So, try UTF-16, but since it works in Notepad++, the best solution would be to simply check how it did it.

You might want to just change the code page for the Project, like [answer by @SaiYeYanNaingAye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517281/5221149) shows, instead of changing the entire workspace.

Comment: The UTF-8 selection also "changed" a multi-line comment into a single line comment. I have serious doubts that the OP is really showing what he sees.